# UITableViewCell layout with after creation

Tags: swift, uitableview, layout, autolayout

I have a tableView custom cell.

Cell:

```
-----------
|  Title  |     
-----------
 |   | <- (Title-Text)Vertical constraint
 | ------------------------------
 | |  View (with label inside)  | 
 | ------------------------------
 |   | <- (View-Text) Vertical constraint
 | <-|--- (Title-Text) Vertical constraint (deactivated by default)
----------
|  Text  |
----------
```

But "View" is not always visible object and I hide him if needed.

I do follow:

1. Make View hidden
2. Deactivate (View-Text) Vertical constraint
3. Activate (Title-Text) Vertical constraint

This I run app. All works fine except the cell height after creation. I see a lot of free space.

Like this:

```
-----------
|         |
|         |
|  Title  |  
|         |
|         |
-----------
 | <- (Title-Text) Vertical constraint
----------
|  Text  |
----------
```

But if I rotate device or scroll down add becomes normal.

Like this:

```
-----------
|  Title  |  
-----------
 | <- (Title-Text) Vertical constraint
----------
|  Text  |
----------
```

How make normal cell height after creation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set height constraint of view is zero instead of hidden?

Comment: This view have label inside. Also with (top,left,right and bottom) constraints.

Answer (score 0):

It could be your `content hugging`priority for your `title`. Have you try setting the priority higher than the other vertical constraint?

Comment: I can set content hugging to another item or constraint. I this way will stretch other item or constraint.

Comment: Is your title and text both UILabel ? Also is the vertical spacing to TOP layout guide set for title and spacing to bottom set for text?

Comment: Both UILabel, all constraints set normal (top,left,right and bottom). I can fix this problem, if I will call reloadData() in viewDidAppear(). But maybe we can find another way.

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question previously. So you are looking for a dynamic cell height base on the content. Have you try setting the tableView.estimatedRowHeight and tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension ?